Bind mongodb replicaset behind Traefik proxy server with TLS
I have mongodb replicaset with Traefik. I configured the mongodb with 3 instances using docker compose (I do understant that is not optimal with all mongo instances in one server - let us skip that part). I want to use Traefik as a proxy server to support TCP security with letsencrypts. I managed to configure my websites with TLS but I am unable to connect to mongodb via mongo compass application. All instances using Traefik network.
I tried to use the following configuration
mongodb compose file
networks:
  starlink:
    name: traefik_starlink
    external: true

services:
  #  If on a linux server, use the hostname provided by the docker compose file
  #  e.g. HOSTNAME = mongo1, mongo2, mongo3

  #  If on MacOS add the following to your /etc/hosts file.
  #  127.0.0.1  mongo1
  #  127.0.0.1  mongo2
  #  127.0.0.1  mongo3
  #  And use localhost as the HOSTNAME
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: mongo1
    command:
      [
        "--replSet",
        "rs0",
        "--bind_ip_all",
        "--port",
        "27018",
        "--keyFile",
        "/etc/mongodb/pki/keyfile",
      ]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    networks:
      - starlink
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/rs_keyfile:/etc/mongodb/pki/keyfile
      - ./data/mongo/mongo1_data:/data/db
      - ./data/mongo/mongo1_config:/data/configdb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo1.entrypoints=mongo_db_1
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo1.service=mongo1
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo1.tls=true
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo1.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
      - traefik.tcp.services.mongo1.loadbalancer.server.port=27018
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo1.tls.domains[0].main=${DOMAIN}
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo1.rule=HostSNI(`mongo.${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo1.tls.passthrough=true

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: mongo2
    command:
      [
        "--replSet",
        "rs0",
        "--bind_ip_all",
        "--port",
        "27019",
        "--keyFile",
        "/etc/mongodb/pki/keyfile",
      ]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27019:27019
    networks:
      - starlink
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/rs_keyfile:/etc/mongodb/pki/keyfile
      - ./data/mongo/mongo2_data:/data/db
      - ./data/mongo/mongo2_config:/data/configdb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo2.entrypoints=mongo_db_2
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo2.service=mongo2
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo2.tls=true
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo2.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
      - traefik.tcp.services.mongo2.loadbalancer.server.port=27018
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo2.tls.domains[0].main=${DOMAIN}
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo2.rule=HostSNI(`mongo.${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo2.tls.passthrough=true

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: mongo3
    container_name: mongo3
    command:
      [
        "--replSet",
        "rs0",
        "--bind_ip_all",
        "--port",
        "27020",
        "--keyFile",
        "/etc/mongodb/pki/keyfile",
      ]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27020:27020
    networks:
      - starlink
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/rs_keyfile:/etc/mongodb/pki/keyfile
      - ./data/mongo/mongo3_data:/data/db
      - ./data/mongo/mongo3_config:/data/configdb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo3.entrypoints=mongo_db_3
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo3.service=mongo3
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo3.tls=true
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo3.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
      - traefik.tcp.services.mongo3.loadbalancer.server.port=27018
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo3.tls.domains[0].main=${DOMAIN}
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo3.rule=HostSNI(`mongo.${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mongo3.tls.passthrough=true

From the mongodb replicaset, I can see that the instances can see each other and the replicaset configuration is set successfully.
Running "rs.status()"
rs0 [direct: secondary] test> rs.status()
{
  set: 'rs0',
  date: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:52.394Z"),
  myState: 2,
  term: Long("55"),
  syncSourceHost: 'mongo1:27018',
  syncSourceId: 0,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1719263180, i: 1 }),
  electionParticipantMetrics: {
    votedForCandidate: true,
    electionTerm: Long("55"),
    lastVoteDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T20:55:40.686Z"),
    electionCandidateMemberId: 0,
    voteReason: '',
    lastAppliedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719262514, i: 1 }), t: Long("53") },
    maxAppliedOpTimeInSet: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719262514, i: 1 }), t: Long("53") },
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T20:55:40.708Z"),
    newTermAppliedDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T20:55:41.191Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'mongo1:27018',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 682,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:51.525Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:51.023Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1719262540, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T20:55:40.000Z"),
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 55
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'mongo2:27019',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 684,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo1:27018',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 55,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'mongo3:27020',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 682,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }), t: Long("55") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:50.754Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:51.527Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2024-06-24T21:06:51.525Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo1:27018',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 55
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("e741ccfce88c1a4956338a7b086bb3676a8230e9", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7381057184014008325")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1719263210, i: 1 })
}

Traefik compose file is configured as follow:
networks:
  starlink:
    driver: bridge

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false

      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.mongo_db_1.address=:27021
      - --entrypoints.mongo_db_2.address=:27022
      - --entrypoints.mongo_db_3.address=:27023
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.websecure.asDefault=true
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt

      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
      #- --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=${EMAIL}
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json

    networks:
      - starlink

    ports:
      - 27021:27018
      - 27022:27019
      - 27023:27020
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt

    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`nginx.${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
      - traefik.http.middlewares.httpsonly.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.httpsonly.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      - traefik.http.routers.httpsonly.middlewares=httpsonly

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=auth
      - traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_PASSWORD_BASIC_AUTH}

I tried to connect using the following connection string
mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@mongo.rocketdev.dev:27021,mongo.rocketdev.dev:27022,mongo.rocketdev.dev:27023/?replicaSet=rs0 but I'm always getting "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms"
This is an image from Traefik dashboard
enter image description here
Can someone help me understanding what is the issue?

What is the reason to use Traefik? You can configure TLS also in MongoDB. You cannot use ReplicaSet with a load balancer. For write operations you always have to connect to PRIMARY. For reading you can also use a SECONDARY but this you do by setting readPreference

I am a bit surprised, that your replica set works fine without running rs.initiate(...) How can you connect to replica set when connection is actually failing? MongoDB has no HTTP interface, not clear what you try to do.

@WernfriedDomscheit, TBH, I did not think about configuring mongodb directly with TLS. I will give it a try and see what I can do.
Regarding rs.intiate() For sure I did that step but did not mention that since my issue was focusing on securing mongodb. Since all my instance in one network and they can see each other, I accessed on container and initiate the configuration.
Thank you for the comments here. I will give it a try.
